# Can i convert the new hair curves to regular curves?

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I'm slowly trying to work with the new hair curves and i for our game we have 'stylized hair'. So i have a profile shape for each hair curve but i'm not able to twist the curves anymore and for the life of me i can not find a way to convert this to regular curves so i can then later twist them.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? I'm assuming there's a way with the geometry nodes but i have no clue and this is driving me bananas.

Much appreciate any help with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try the *Set Curve Tilt* node. Please note that the new *Curves* will replace the existing *Curve* objects in the future but [Blender 3.3](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.3) is still under development. Not everything is implemented yet and there might be bugs. For example, there is no *Edit* mode available yet for the new Hair Curves. Do not use alpha versions for production!